# Paragraph between Subfigures

Tags: floats, subfloats, paragraphs

i need to write in between the subfigure. example shown below.

\begin{figure}
\subfigure[][]{...}
\label

and then the paragraph continues. without change in font, size and line spacing. after the paragraph ends, the subfigure and figure ends later, as shown below.

\subfigure[][]{...}
\label
\end{figure}

but the problem here is the in-between paragraph. it comes as a bold-font with no line spacing. i want it in a normal alignment made in the document.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could use two separate figures [ht] and `\ContinuedFloat` in the second.  That would allow a page break between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you want?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subcaptionbox{aaa\label{aaa}}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{aaa\label{aaa}}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{aaa\label{aaa}}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\subcaptionbox{aaa\label{aaa}}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{aaa\label{aaa}}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{aaa\label{aaa}}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}}
\caption{bbb}
\label{bbb}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the response and clarifying my doubts exactly. and may i ask one more doubt, that, can we change the format of the caption, instead of "(a) aaa ,(b) aaa",  i need it as "Figure 1: (a) aaa, Figure 1: (b) aaa," so on. is that possible ??

Comment: You can try `\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\figurename\space\thefigure:\space(\alph{subfigure})}` and you should read the doc of `subcaption`.